# Java Callable and Future not running asychronously

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

I am using Java 7.

I  have a method I would like to execute in a new thread (asynchronously) and allow the rest of the process to continue.  However, I have the following code, but it still executes synchronously.

```
executeBookingAndApprovalConcurrently(autoBookingEnabled, tripDTO, approvalRequestDetails, approvalRequest, quoteResponse, tripRequirementsResponse, evaluatorsList, evaluationTree, memberId, properties, session);
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Executed booking and approval requests in a new thread." );
```

and

```
private void executeBookingAndApprovalConcurrently(final boolean autoBookingEnabled, final TripDTO tripDTO, final ApprovalRequestDetails approvalRequestDetails, final ApprovalRequest approvalRequest, final QuoteResponse quoteResponse, final TripRequirementsResponse tripRequirementsResponse, final List<List<Evaluator>> evaluatorsList, final List<EvaluationApprovalTree> evaluationTree, final Long memberId, final Map<String,Object> properties, final HttpSession session) {

    Callable<Void> taskBookAndApprove = new Callable<Void>() {
        public Void call() {
            executeBookingAndApproval(autoBookingEnabled, tripDTO, approvalRequestDetails, approvalRequest, quoteResponse, tripRequirementsResponse, evaluatorsList, evaluationTree, memberId, properties, session);
            return null;
        }
    };

    Future<Void> futureBookAndApprove = executorService.submit(taskBookAndApprove);
    try {
        futureBookAndApprove.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "InterruptedException Error calling executeBookingAndApproval in a new thread.", e);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "ExecutionException Error calling executeBookingAndApproval in a new thread.", e);
    }

}
```

and

```
private void executeBookingAndApproval(final boolean autoBookingEnabled, final TripDTO tripDTO, final ApprovalRequestDetails approvalRequestDetails, final ApprovalRequest approvalRequest, final QuoteResponse quoteResponse, final TripRequirementsResponse tripRequirementsResponse, final List<List<Evaluator>> evaluatorsList, final List<EvaluationApprovalTree> evaluationTree, final Long memberId, final Map<String,Object> properties, final HttpSession session) {
    // do stuff that takes a long time
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Called executeBookingAndApproval successfully in a new thread.");
}
```

I would like it to print:

> Executed booking and approval requests in a new thread.

> Called executeBookingAndApproval successfully in a new thread.

But it prints in this order:

> Called executeBookingAndApproval successfully in a new thread.

> Executed booking and approval requests in a new thread.

Comment: [`Future#get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) blocks.

Comment: @sp00m thanks for your  reply. If `.get()` blocks, what should I rather use?

Comment: You could just remove this line. It's not `Future#get()` that triggers the job, but `executorService#submit()`.

Answer (score 1):

executeBookingAndApprovalConcurrently should return the Future so that you can call `futureBookAndApprove.get();` outside the method. Eg.

```java
final Future<Void> futureBookAndApprove = executeBookingAndApprovalConcurrently(autoBookingEnabled, tripDTO, approvalRequestDetails, approvalRequest, quoteResponse, tripRequirementsResponse, evaluatorsList, evaluationTree, memberId, properties, session);
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Executed booking and approval requests in a new thread." );

try {
    futureBookAndApprove.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "InterruptedException Error calling executeBookingAndApproval in a new thread.", e);
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "ExecutionException Error calling executeBookingAndApproval in a new thread.", e);
}

private Future<Void> executeBookingAndApprovalConcurrently(final boolean autoBookingEnabled, final TripDTO tripDTO, final ApprovalRequestDetails approvalRequestDetails, final ApprovalRequest approvalRequest, final QuoteResponse quoteResponse, final TripRequirementsResponse tripRequirementsResponse, final List<List<Evaluator>> evaluatorsList, final List<EvaluationApprovalTree> evaluationTree, final Long memberId, final Map<String,Object> properties, final HttpSession session) {

    return executorService.submit(() -> {
        executeBookingAndApproval(autoBookingEnabled, tripDTO, approvalRequestDetails, approvalRequest, quoteResponse, tripRequirementsResponse, evaluatorsList, evaluationTree, memberId, properties, session);
        return null; 
    });

}
```

when you call `get()` the method blocks to wait for the response. So whilst the task would have executed asynchronously, it will not appear as you want unless you perform the `get()` after the initial `logger.log` line.